# GCDAsyncSocket not releasing port

Tags: ios, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

I'm using the following code:

```
    _broadcastReceiveSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:_broadcastHandler delegateQueue:_broadcastQueue];

    BOOL successfulStart = [_broadcastReceiveSocket bindToPort:BROADCAST_PORT error:error]
    && [_broadcastReceiveSocket joinMulticastGroup:BROADCAST_HOST error:error]
    && [_broadcastReceiveSocket beginReceiving:error];
```

To start a socket listening for UDP broadcasts.

But I can only seem to run this code once in the simulator. After that I get an error back saying "Address already is use" from the bindToPort command.

The only way I have found so far to fix this is to reboot the machine. Which from a developers point of view is totally impractical.

I have had this working just fine. Any ideas what could have changed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the socket (or destroy it completely) by sending it the `close` message.

Comment: Tricky when you stop the app by hitting the stop button in Xcode :-)